# IF and or Formula in Excel 2019

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

```
=IF(OR(Database!M4="male",Database!M4="female"),Database!MB4,"")
```

The Result shows me zero (0) I want to, if the cell has no data the result should be blank (empty) not zero. thanks in advance dear friends

Comment: It must not show zero `0`. Can you put a screenshot to your post.

Comment: You are checking M4 for the input male or female, and if so then it will show the value of MB4. Is this intentional? Or should it look in M4 instead to show male/female?

Comment: `=IF(Database!M4="","",<urFormula>)` should do.. pls verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ISBLANK` to check if a cell is blank.

`=IF(OR(Database!M4="male",Database!M4="female"),IF(ISBLANK(Database!MB4), "", Database!MB4),"")`

Comment: If this worked for you, please mark it as accepted answer using the tick icon on the left

Answer (score 1):

So if cell m4 can only be male, female or blank then try this:

```
=if(Database!m4="","",Database!m4)
```

Based on the logic that if it is not blank then it has to be male or female - unless it decides to be non-binary….